# How to Refactor this big if condition

Tags: c#, refactoring

How to refactoring this big if condition?  weapon is a list and it;s gameobject

How to refactoring this big if condition?  weapon is a list and it;s gameobject

```
public class Customanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> weapon;
    public static Customanger singleton;
    private void Awake() => singleton = this;
};
```

```
if (Customanger.singleton.weapon[1].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[2].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[3].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[4].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[5].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[8].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[10].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[12].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[13].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[14].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[15].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[16].activeSelf ||
    Customanger.singleton.weapon[17].activeSelf)
{
    dosomething();
}
```

Comment: The answers may vary depending if your check loops thru all the weapons or only a subset of them.

Comment: @Cleptus, I updated my answer to support solutions for all as well as subset of weapons

Comment: What type is `Customanger.singleton.weapon`? An array, a list, a dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0),

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
> condition.

```
//Here I considered length of Weapon array/list is 17
if (Customanger.singleton.weapon.Any(x => x.activeSelf))
{
    dosomething();
}
```

---

If you would like to check same condition for subset of weapons, then you can try below,

```
var subSetOfWeapons = Customanger.singleton.weapon.GetRange(1, 17);

if (subSetOfWeapons.Any(x => x.activeSelf))
{
    dosomething();
}
```

For more details: [List.GetRange(int index, int count)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?view=net-6.0)

Comment: This answer could be improved by addressing the fact that OP needs to check a _subset_ of the weapons, not all of them.

Comment: @AstridE., I updated condition to support subset of weapons.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which types you are using. What I did is check which pattern is recurrent. I see that you always access the weapon list/array. Normally indexers can be iterated.

Some assumes are made because of the incompleteness of information.

You could write a loop for it:

```
private bool CheckActiveSelf(List<WeaponThing> weapons)
{
    // iterate each weapon
    foreach(var weapon in weapons)
        // when activeSelf, return true
        if(weapon.activeSelf)
            return true;
   
    return false;
}


// instead of passing the Customanger, you should pass the deepest
// level. So when the weapon system is used elsewhere, you can still
// use the method.
if(CheckActiveSelf(Customanger.singleton.weapon))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: We can re-write entire `CheckActiveSelf()` method in one line using Linq. i.e. `.Any()`

Comment: Yes, I probably would do that also, but My intention was to make him aware of recurring pattern and how to solve it with a loop. Ofcourse `Any` is a great solution either.

Comment: This answer could be improved by addressing the fact that OP needs to check a _subset_ of the weapons, not all of them.

Comment: It will probably a property which could be checked in `Any` as wel. Like `if(weapon.activeSelf && weapon.hasAmmo)` or `.Any(x => x.activeSelf && x.hasAmmo));` . He will probably (hopefully) not check by index.

Comment: I agree that they will _hopefully_ do that, but seeing as they are using indices (or possibly dictionary keys) in their question, I wouldn't expect it. Either way, it was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever this check means, in OOP world it should be implemented as instance method (or property) with meaningful name in `Customanger` class:

```
class Customanger
{
    private static int[] activeWeaponIndexes = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
    public bool HasActiveWeapon => activeWeaponIndexes.Any(x => weapon[x].activeSelf);
}
```

Then condition will be reduced to:

```
if (Customanger.singleton.HasActiveWeapon) { \*do smth*\ }
```

Comment: or a fancy extension method `.HasActiveWeapon(this IEnumerable<Weapon>, params int[] weaponIndexes)`

Comment: @Cleptus, `weaponIndexes` is the sticking point here. they are a bunch of magic numbers, which IMO should be incapsulated in Customanger. so no -  no fancy extension methods. also indices don't works well with IEnumerable

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it, you can include or exclude items from your collection and than check for the "activeSelf" flag
ex:

````
List<GameObject> excludedList = new List<GameObject>() { 
Customanger.singleton.weapon[1], 
Customanger.singleton.weapon[3], 
Customanger.singleton.weapon[5]};
if (Customanger.singleton.weapon.Except(excludedList).Any(x => x.activeSelf))
    dosomething();
    ```
````

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that:

```
var weaponIds = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };

var weapons = weaponIds.Select(x => Customanger.singleton.weapon[x]);

if (weapons.Where(x => x.activeSelf).Any())
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

You could probably do better than that by splitting your weapon arrays into categories maybe? I can't help you more with the code you provided.

EDIT: Removed the completely unecessary ToList()

Answer (score 3):

How did you decide that specifically `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 }` are the relevant weapon indices?

---

If they are all indices of weapons that distinguish themselves from the remaining weapons by *fulfilling a certain condition*, you could identify the relevant weapons directly and not bother with the indices.

As an example, you could use use `.Where()` to filter out the relevant weapons:

```csharp
Customanger.singleton.weapon
    .Where(weapon => <weapon fulfills condition>)
```

Let's say the condition is that the relevant weapons all have a common trait: they all belong to scenes that have been loaded. The condition can then be defined as:

```csharp
<weapon fulfills condition> = weapon.scene.isLoaded
```

, and you can filter your relevant weapons as follows:

```csharp
IEnumerable<GameObject> weaponsInLoadedScenes = Customanger.singleton.weapon
    .Where(weapon => weapon.scene.isLoaded);
```

Now, you can use `.Any()` to perform your original `if` check on these relevant weapons:

```csharp
if (weaponsInLoadedScenes.Any(weapon => weapon.activeSelf))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Both `.Where()` and `.Any()` are found in the namespace *System.Linq*.

---

If, on the other hand, the relevant weapon indices are *not* selected based on common weapon traits, I would basically refer to [Another One's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72486634/how-to-refactor-this-big-if-condition#72487116).

First, create a collection of the relevant weapon indices (preferably using a variable name that somehow describes *why* these are relevant weapon indices):

```csharp
var relevantWeaponIndices = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
```

Then, verify conditions; either by first explicitly defining the relevant weapons:

```csharp
var relevantWeapons = relevantWeaponIndices
    .Select(index => Customanger.singleton.weapon[index]);

if (relevantWeapons.Any(weapon => weapon.activeSelf))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

or by getting the relevant weapons inline:

```csharp
if (relevantWeaponIndices.Any(index => Customanger.singleton.weapon[index].activeSelf))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Both `.Select()` and `.Any()` are found in the namespace *System.Linq*.